# Linux "find" returns all files

Tags: linux, find

A few days ago I was reading about the Linux `find` tool and based on that I issued the following command to see if I have the `Python.h` file:

```
find . 'Python.h'
```

The problem is that all files in current dir and subdirs are returned. Shouldn't I get what I'm looking for?

Comment: You didn't tell find what to look for, only *where* to look for; `find` interprets both `.` and `'Python.h'` as starting places for its operation. But you have to use at least one selector to tell it what to filter by. That being said, you probably want to use `locate` if you don't know, where exactly in your system a file might be.

Answer (score 3):

You left out the parameter specifier `-name`:

```
find ./ -name 'Python.h'
```

`find` will recurse through all directories in the current directory. If you just want to see whether you have a file in the current directory, use `ls`:

```
ls Python.h
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -name switch:

```
find . -name  'Python.h'
```

Otherwise it takes the name as location to look at.

Comment: So one can list multiple directory trees and find will search all of them?